# Deciding about dimensionality reduction with PCA

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have 2D data (I have a zero mean normalized data). I know the covariance matrix, eigenvalues and eigenvectors of it. I want to decide whether to reduce the dimension to 1 or not (I use principal component analysis, PCA). How can I decide?  Is there any methodology for it?

I am looking sth. like if you look at this ratio and if this ratio is high than it is logical to go on with dimensionality reduction.

**PS 1:** Does PoV (Proportion of variation) stands for it?

**PS 2:** Here is an answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22569/pca-and-proportion-of-variance-explained does it a criteria to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PoV (Proportion of variation) represents how much information of data will remain relatively to using all of them. It ***may*** be used for that purpose. If POV is high than less information will be lose.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort your eigenvalues by magnitude then pick the highest 1 or 2 values. Eigenvalues with a very small relative value can be considered for exclusion. You can then translate data values and using only the top 1 or 2 eigenvectors you'll get dimensions for plotting results. This will give a visual representation of the PCA split. Also check out scikit-learn for more on PCA. Precisions, recalls, F1-scores will tell you how well it works

from http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_pca_step_by_step.html...

Step 1: 3D Example

"For our simple example, where we are reducing a 3-dimensional feature space to a 2-dimensional feature subspace, we are combining the two eigenvectors with the highest eigenvalues to construct our d×kd×k-dimensional eigenvector matrix WW.

```
matrix_w = np.hstack((eig_pairs[0][1].reshape(3,1),
                  eig_pairs[1][1].reshape(3,1)))
print('Matrix W:\n', matrix_w)

>>>Matrix W:
[[-0.49210223 -0.64670286]
[-0.47927902 -0.35756937]
[-0.72672348  0.67373552]]"
```

Step 2: 3D Example

"
In the last step, we use the 2×32×3-dimensional matrix WW that we just computed to transform our samples onto the new subspace via the equation
                                y=W^T×x

```
transformed = matrix_w.T.dot(all_samples)
assert transformed.shape == (2,40), "The matrix is not 2x40 dimensional."
```